# Multiplication operator is densely defined.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I saw the question [Multiplication Operator on $L^2$ is densely defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166217/multiplication-operator-on-l2-is-densely-defined)

Disintegration by parts answers using the following argument.

If $f \perp \mathcal{D} (L)$ then $\frac{1}{m^2+1} f \in \mathcal{D} (L)$.

I can't understand why this is true, $f \perp \mathcal{D} (L)$ means $\langle f,g \rangle_{L^2} =0$ for all $g \in \mathcal{D}(L)$.
Can you explain why does it follow that $\frac{1}{m^2+1} f \in \mathcal{D} (L)$.

Comment: $\frac1{m^2+1}f\in D(L)$ is true for general $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac 1{m^{2}+1}f   \in \mathcal D(L)$ because $m (\frac 1{m^{2}+1}f) \in L^{2}$: note that $f \in L^{2}$ and $|\frac m{m^{2}+1}| \leq 1/2$.  Since $f \perp \mathcal{D} (L)$ it follows that $ \int \overline f \frac 1{m^{2}+1}f =0$ which implies $f=0$ a.e. Hence, $\mathcal D(L)$  is dense.

Comment: I see, if you allow me I have one more question. I know that for $X =\mathbb{R}$ $C_c^{\infty }(\mathbb{R}$) is a subspace of $\mathcal{D} (L)$, but $C_c^{\infty }(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, does this prove that $\mathcal{D} (L)$ is dense?

Comment: Yes, it does prove that $\mathcal D(L)$ is dense in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$. @Dag_Nilsen

Comment: But how did you prove that $C_c^{\infty} $ is dense in $\mathcal D(L)$? You need some assumption on $m$, not just measurability.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of a special case for $m$ where this is true.